# Create SPFx webpart based on existing webpart (Text)

Tags: spfx-webparts

Is there a way to create an SPFx webpart that extends or is otherwise based on an existing built-in webpart? In particular, I want to create a text editor using the default "Text" webpart.

I would like to use the built-in functionality, not mimic it by importing CKE myself.

Something like this maybe?

```
export default class MyTextWebPart extends TextClientSideWebPart<IMyTextWebPartProps> {
```

Instead of

```
export default class MyTextWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMyTextWebPartProps> {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it is not possible. You would have to be able to reference React component which cannot be done outside the SPFx package because it is already transpiled from TypeSript to Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Lukas! This is inside the SPFx package, does that change the answer? I updated the question to be more specific.